# Webservice client gives error because of HTTP status 302 while deployed in JBoss but running fine as standalone Java

Tags: java, jboss

I have a webservice client built using Apache CXF.

When I deploy the client in JBoss and run it gives the following error:

```
    Failed to create service.: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: org.apache.cxf.service.factory.ServiceConstructionException: Failed to create service
    Caused by: javax.wsdl.WSDLException: WSDLException: faultCode=PARSER_ERROR: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
```

In the log, I am getting the Header fields as:

```
        null: [HTTP/1.1 302 Found]
        Content-Language: [en-US]
        Content-Length: [0]
        X-WebKit-CSP: [default-src 'self']
        X-XSS-Protection: [1; mode=block]
        X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies: [master-only]
        Location: [http://<masked>/sms-ws/ServiceImplService/ServiceImplService.wsdl]
        Connection: [Keep-Alive]
        Server: [Apache]
        X-Powered-By: [Servlet/3.0]
        X-Content-Type-Options: [nosniff]
        X-Frame-Options: [SAMEORIGIN]
        Vary: [Accept-Encoding,User-Agent]
        Date: [Tue, 05 Sep 2017 06:35:04 GMT]
        Keep-Alive: [timeout=5, max=99]
        Content-Type: [text/plain]
```

However when I run the same client as Standalone Java (through Eclipse), it gives the desired output.

How to solve this?

Comment: I came across that we need to enable AutoRedirect=true in cxf client configuration. Added the same in cxf.xml but still not working.